# How do I read the first 10 rows of a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a way to read a sample of a DataFrame in pandas like:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('path_to_my_csv/csv.csv', header=True, sample=10)

#or 
df = pd.read_parquet('path_to_my_parquet/csv.parquet', engine="pyarrow", sample=10)
```

What I want is to load on the X (10 is this case) first rows of my Data, for test purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load only the first 10 non-header rows using `nrows`

```
df = pd.read_csv('path_to_my_csv/csv.csv', header=True, nrows=10)
```

Comment: This looks good. it wouldn't read the entire `csv` but only the first 10 rows. Upvoted!

Comment: @jezrael OP needs the first 10 rows of data as opposed to sampling 10 rows

Comment: Agree, so closed like dupe.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_csv('path_to_my_csv/csv.csv', header=True).head(10)
```

Your df will have the first 10 rows of your csv file

Comment: This solution will not scale well for larger datasets