# Reduce the size of csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file.
I am using it to do some machine learning stuffs on it.
But, my dataset in csv file is very large.
For doing some practice stuffs, I want to reduce its size.
Like, in my original csv file, I have 200000 data items. But for practice I want to create a csv file with first 100 data items. How can I do this with python.

Note: **I want a new csv file of 100 data items.**

I tried using to_csv method of pandas library.

```
x.to_csv('tempo.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

The above method made a new file.
But, it gives me error for following code:

```
x['Keywords']=x['Keywords'].map(lambda x: convert(x))
```

Error is:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  x['Keywords']=x['Keywords'].map(lambda x: convert(x))
```

Comment: Or this one probably has a better answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69203560/how-do-i-read-the-first-10-rows-of-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: This just stores n data items in a variable. I want to create a new file which will contain this n data items.

Comment: You can write the resulting dataframe to a file with `to_csv()` just as you already have in your code here.

Comment: But, by doing this, I get the same error on each line. Error is given in question.

Comment: I think the error you posted in your question has nothing to do with reducing the size of your CSV file, as you state in your title. You should post a new question just for the error. Be sure to include a [mcve] that reproduces the exact error message you ask about.